# What is the best design for a table that contains many columns?

Tags: layout, data-tables

I designed a table to display a set of data, some take up a lot of space, and the table contains many columns .. Because of that I had no space to display the rest of the columns

Comment: If you are finding your designs aren't usable, consider hiring a designer!

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of articles that teach you how to manage big data tables. 
Make the columns customizable by the user. Allow them to create their own table by choosing what columns they see.
Allow them to reorder columns.
Create a horizontal scroll if needed 
Make the headers sticky if the table is long either vertically or horizontally.